# How to get data from HTML using regex

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I have following HTML

```
<table class="profile-stats">
  <tr>
    <td class="stat">
      <div class="statnum">8</div>
      <div class="statlabel"> Tweets </div>
    </td>
    <td class="stat">
        <a href="/THEDJMHA/following">
          <div class="statnum">13</div>
          <div class="statlabel"> Following </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="stat stat-last">
        <a href="/THEDJMHA/followers">
          <div class="statnum">22</div>
          <div class="statlabel"> Followers </div>
        </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get value from `<td class="stat stat-last">` => `<div class="statnum">` = `22`.

I have tried the follow regex but does not any found match.

```
/<div\sclass="statnum">^(.)\?<\/div>/ig
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting. Niether the `/g` flag nor the `^` anchor would work there. And the escaped `\?` is misplaced as well. A typical placeholder is `(.*?)`. -- But if you're that unversed with regexp: the off-topic answer to your question would be to use a DOM traversal frontend (such as `qp($html)->find(".statnum")`, or plain DOMDocument if you'd prefer tedious and brittle).

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `^` in that place.. Try this `/<div\s+class="statnum">([^>]+)<\/div>/ig`.

Comment: Anyway, that's not a good idea to parse HTML with regexps. You always will find a new bug.

Comment: If I'm not wrong then, what actually you needed over here is the text content of `div` i.e. `8,13,22`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to accomplish this using a parser.

```
<?php
$html = '<table class="profile-stats">
  <tr>
    <td class="stat">
      <div class="statnum">8</div>
      <div class="statlabel"> Tweets </div>
    </td>
    <td class="stat">
        <a href="/THEDJMHA/following">
          <div class="statnum">13</div>
          <div class="statlabel"> Following </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="stat stat-last">
        <a href="/THEDJMHA/followers">
          <div class="statnum">22</div>
          <div class="statlabel"> Followers </div>
        </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
$doc = new DOMDocument(); //make a dom object
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach ($tds as $cell) { //loop through all Cells
    if(strpos($cell->getAttribute('class'), 'stat-last')){
        $divs = $cell->getElementsByTagName('div');
        foreach($divs as $div) { // loop through all divs of the cell
            if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'statnum'){
                echo $div->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 22

...or using an xpath...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); //make a dom object
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$statnums = $xpath->query("//td[@class='stat stat-last']/a/div[@class='statnum']");
foreach($statnums as $statnum) {
    echo $statnum->nodeValue;
}
```

Output:

> 22

or if you realllly wanted to regex it...

```
<?php
$html = '<table class="profile-stats">
  <tr>
    <td class="stat">
      <div class="statnum">8</div>
      <div class="statlabel"> Tweets </div>
    </td>
    <td class="stat">
        <a href="/THEDJMHA/following">
          <div class="statnum">13</div>
          <div class="statlabel"> Following </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="stat stat-last">
        <a href="/THEDJMHA/followers">
          <div class="statnum">22</div>
          <div class="statlabel"> Followers </div>
        </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
preg_match('~td class=".*?stat-last">.*?<div class="statnum">(.*?)<~s', $html, $num);
echo $num[1];
```

Output:

> 22

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/kM6kI2/1

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better if you use an XML parser for that instead of regex. SimpleXML can do the job for you: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: And how do one get the value from the node with the software you suggested?

Comment: HTML is a specific XML, so it will work with HTML. The SimpleXMLElement class will contain all data related with the node.

Answer (score 2):

```
/<td class="stat stat-last">.*?<div class="statnum">(\d+)/si
```

Your match is in the first capture group.  Notice the use of the s option at the end.  Makes '.' match new line characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your pattern like that:

```
/<div\sclass="statnum">(.*?)<\/div>/ig
```