# DOMXPath to find specific image tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, domxpath

My question is very direct. Here is my `html` dom,

```
<html>
   ...
  <div class="A B">
    <div class="C">
       <img src="..." >
    </div>
  <div>
  ...
  <div class="A">
  </div>
...
</html>
```

Now I want to get the image's src in `div[class="A B"]-><div class="C">-><img>` using `DOMXPath` in `php` code.

The main puzzle is that I do not know how to write it's path correctly.

---

**Update**

I have tried [How to get data from HTML using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118367/how-to-get-data-from-html-using-regex/32118963#32118963), but it doesn't work still.

The actual html structure is :
[image]

My `php` code:

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTML($html);
   $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $XPath = new DOMXPath($doc);
   $vipImg = $XPath->query('//div[@class="show-midpic active-pannel"]/a/div[@class="zoomPad"]/img');
   var_dump($vipImg);
   foreach($vipImg as $vip)
   {
      var_dump($vip);
   }
```

And the output is :

> object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130858/get-img-src-with-php

Comment: @GeorgeH The main puzzle is that I do not know how to write it's path correctly.

Comment: Here's an answer I did last week that is pretty similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118367/how-to-get-data-from-html-using-regex/32118963#32118963.